# Ajax not sending serialized data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have problems with my jQuery. I'm sending an AJAX request and it's not sending the serialized data to the PHP file. This is the jQuery:

```
var str = $("#emailverify").serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'emailverify.php?task=verificacion',
    type: 'post',
    data: str,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $(".msg_veri").html('<img src="images/ajaxcart_loader.gif />');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        $(".msg_veri").html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
        //$("#btnsendmail").attr( "disabled", false );
        $("#btnvalidatemail").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

This is the HTML of the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="emailverify">
    <div class="lad_correos">
        <input type="hidden" id="contacto" name="contacto" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cliente']['cookdownnlitemcontacto']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="susnume" name="susnume" value="<?php echo $susnume; ?>">                
        <div class="txt_label">Correos electr&oacute;nicos:</div>
        <input id="email1" name="email1" class="text required email" type="text" placeholder="micorreo@dominio.com" value="<?php echo $emailistos[0]; ?>"/><br>   
    </div>
    <div class="botones">
        <div class="btn_send">
            <!--<input type="button" class="button btn-success" style="visibility:hidden;" value=" Verificar correos " onclick="javascript:sendmail();" id="btnsendmail" />-->
            <!--<input type="button" class="button btn-info" value=" Validar c&oacute;digos " style="visibility:hidden;" id="btnvalidatemail" onclick="javascript:validatemail();" />-->    
            <input type="button" class="button btn-success" onclick="javascript: closepopup();" value=" Verificar correos" id="btnverify" /> <!-- onclick="javascript:verify();" --> 
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is where it should execute in PHP, but its not receiving any post data from the form:

```
<?php  include('../prgs/dbconnect.php');
    $sus_nume = $_POST["susnume"];
    $codigoauto = rand(1000, 9999);
    $estado = 1; // email supuestamente enviado 1

    if ($_POST['email1']) {
        if ($_POST['email1'] != '') {
            $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
            $sqlselect = "select correo from verificacion_correos where susnume='" . $sus_nume . "' and correo='" . $email1 . "';";
            $res1 = mysql_query($sqlselect);
            $arr1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
            $mailchk1 = $arr1[0];
            if ($mailchk1 != $email1 && $mailchk1 != null && $mailchk1 != "") {
                $sqlinsert = "insert into verificacion_correos(`susnume`, `correo`, `codigoverificacion`, `estado`, `fecharegistro`) ";
                $sqlinsert .="values('" . $sus_nume . "','" . $email1 . "','" . $codigoauto . "','" . $estado . "','" . fecha_hora(2) . "');";
    //$sqlinsert .= "update suscriptores set email='" . $email1 . "' where sus_nume=" . $sus_nume . ";";
                $insvalidation = mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
    //$insSus = mysql_query($sqlIns) or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
    echo "1_|_" . $sqlinsert;
```

Comment: have you tried to log (`console.log(str);`) before the ajax request to make sure it has the values?

Comment: thanks i hadn`t though about it...!!!

Comment: how can you not think about that ... it's basic debugging. This site shouldn't be your first point of troubleshooting. You can also inspect the actual request to see what it contains in browser dev tools network